# How to visualize result of cumulative link model using the ordinal package in Rstudio?

Tags: confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I used ordinal GLM with cumulative link model using dependent variables with 5 levels. The objectives are to examine people's attitudes towards pet cat in two countries and to also find out if people who moved from either country to the other has changed their attitudes.
Models were fitted. stepwise deletion was done and independent variables that had more than 0.05 p-values were deleted as shown in the model1 table below.
The table in model 2 has only significant variables. Different links were checked and link with lowest value was selected and also thresholds compered. Analysis below. Pls i need help with how to plot the graph to explain my data.
I'm not an expert in R.  Kindly assist.

```
model1 <- clm(factor (fer_live) ~ factor (age)+ factor (emp) + factor (gender)+ factor (cat)+ factor (born) *factor (live), data = dframe1, na.action = na.exclude)
drop1(model1, test = "Chi") 

Single term deletions

Model:1
factor(fer_live) ~ factor(age) + factor(emp) + factor(gender) + 
    factor(cat) + factor(born) * factor(live)
                          Df    AIC     LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
<none>                       4342.2                      
factor(age)                5 4346.7  14.545  0.012492 *  
factor(emp)                4 4346.1  11.903  0.018086 *  
factor(gender)             2 4342.1   3.930  0.140160    
factor(cat)                1 4347.8   7.667  0.005624 ** 
factor(born):factor(live)  1 4441.1 100.984 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
model2 <- clm(factor (fer_live) ~ factor (age)+ factor (emp) + factor (cat)+ factor (born) *factor (live), data = dframe1, na.action = na.exclude)
drop1(model2, test = "Chi") #gender deleted in model2#
Single term deletions

Model:2 ( significant variables only) 
factor(fer_live) ~ factor(age) + factor(emp) + factor(cat) + 
    factor(born) * factor(live)
                          Df    AIC    LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
<none>                       4342.1                     
factor(age)                5 4347.4 15.348  0.008974 ** 
factor(emp)                4 4346.6 12.463  0.014220 *  
factor(cat)                1 4348.1  8.009  0.004654 ** 
factor(born):factor(live)  1 4438.5 98.420 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


links<-c("logit", "probit", "cloglog", "loglog", "cauchit") ##5 links compared that describes data and link with lowest value selected). 

apply(links, function(link) {
+   clm(factor (fer_live) ~ factor (age)+ factor (emp) + factor (cat)+ factor (born) *factor (live), data = dframe1, na.action = na.exclude, link = link)$logLik
+ })
    logit    probit   cloglog    loglog   cauchit 
-2154.048 -2158.654 -2168.474 -2132.669 -2158.654 

model3=clm(factor (fer_live) ~ factor (age)+ factor (emp) + factor (cat)+ factor (born) *factor (live), data = dframe1, na.action = na.exclude,link="loglog")
model4=clm(factor (fer_live) ~ factor (age)+ factor (emp) + factor (cat)+ factor (born) *factor (live), data = dframe1, na.action = na.exclude,link="loglog",threshold="symmetric")
model5=clm(factor (fer_live) ~ factor (age)+ factor (emp) + factor (cat)+ factor (born) *factor (live), data = dframe1, na.action = na.exclude,link="loglog",threshold="equidistant")
convergence(model2)#basic model
 nobs logLik   niter max.grad cond.H  logLik.Error
 1516 -2154.05 5(1)  1.29e-12 6.4e+02 <1e-10      

                            Estimate Std.Err  Gradient     Error Cor.Dec Sig.Dig
1|2                         -1.33776  0.2119  1.31e-13 -1.54e-14      13      14
2|3                         -0.38517  0.2083  1.45e-13 -1.55e-14      13      13
3|4                          0.02201  0.2084  6.51e-13 -1.56e-14      13      12
4|5                          1.07993  0.2130 -1.29e-12 -1.87e-14      13      14
factor(age)2                -0.18525  0.1787 -1.36e-13 -1.74e-14      13      13
factor(age)3                -0.16118  0.1883 -1.33e-13 -1.72e-14      13      13
factor(age)4                -0.49809  0.2029 -2.67e-14 -1.67e-14      13      13
factor(age)5                -0.75480  0.2459 -1.47e-14 -1.69e-14      13      13
factor(age)6                -0.67798  0.3493 -3.00e-15 -1.60e-14      13      13
factor(emp)1                -0.66868  0.2069 -1.63e-14 -1.15e-14      13      13
factor(emp)2                 0.10322  0.2624 -3.66e-15 -1.38e-15      14      14
factor(emp)3                -0.25901  0.1590 -2.23e-14 -1.23e-15      14      14
factor(emp)4                -0.24702  0.1350  1.44e-13 -1.59e-15      14      14
factor(cat)2                 0.37572  0.1332  3.56e-13 -7.26e-16      14      14
factor(born)2               -0.55809  0.1402 -6.44e-15  1.72e-15      14      14
factor(live)2                1.67886  0.1656  6.14e-13  7.94e-15      13      14
factor(born)2:factor(live)2 -2.07435  0.2131  9.93e-14 -6.87e-15      13      14

Eigen values of Hessian:
2036.041 1046.348  631.170  342.256  169.926  133.896  112.592   86.216   70.571   59.341   52.087   35.560   23.544   19.685   13.511    7.407    3.194 

Convergence message from clm:
(0) successful convergence 
In addition: Absolute and relative convergence criteria were met 

convergence(model3)#best model with link only
 nobs logLik   niter max.grad cond.H  logLik.Error
 1516 -2132.67 6(1)  6.62e-07 4.7e+02 <1e-10      

                            Estimate Std.Err  Gradient     Error Cor.Dec Sig.Dig
1|2                         -0.71917 0.13321 -5.78e-07 -2.35e-11      10      10
2|3                         -0.06013 0.13240 -2.26e-08 -3.57e-11      10       9
3|4                          0.23825 0.13344 -3.39e-08 -3.85e-11      10      10
4|5                          1.03920 0.13908 -3.40e-08 -5.03e-11       9      10
factor(age)2                -0.10695 0.11323  1.45e-07  2.18e-11      10      10
factor(age)3                -0.11388 0.12008  1.99e-07 -9.50e-12      10      10
factor(age)4                -0.46521 0.12984  1.22e-07  1.83e-10       9       9
factor(age)5                -0.62302 0.15928  7.81e-08  2.50e-10       9       9
factor(age)6                -0.59415 0.23735  3.85e-08 -2.80e-11      10      10
factor(emp)1                -0.49107 0.13774  8.46e-08  1.17e-10       9       9
factor(emp)2                 0.14932 0.18078  8.51e-08  1.08e-10       9       9
factor(emp)3                -0.20507 0.10500  1.43e-07  1.93e-10       9       9
factor(emp)4                -0.22115 0.08774  2.62e-07  7.08e-11       9       9
factor(cat)2                 0.36442 0.08810  5.73e-07 -1.70e-10       9       9
factor(born)2               -0.47815 0.09619  6.61e-07 -1.80e-11      10      10
factor(live)2                0.66766 0.09115  6.62e-07 -3.57e-11      10      10
factor(born)2:factor(live)2 -1.24591 0.13211  6.59e-07  2.39e-09       8       9

Eigen values of Hessian:
3835.564 2486.627 1199.702  565.256  383.259  302.582  270.215  200.532  160.582  142.717  106.516   77.510   54.443   45.032   32.830   15.706    8.111 

Convergence message from clm:
(0) successful convergence 
In addition: Absolute and relative convergence criteria were met 

convergence(model4)#best model with link and threshold
 nobs logLik   niter max.grad cond.H  logLik.Error
 1516 -2135.60 6(1)  6.58e-07 4.2e+02 <1e-10      

                            Estimate Std.Err  Gradient     Error Cor.Dec Sig.Dig
central.1                   -0.02994 0.13221 -5.97e-07 -3.58e-11      10       9
central.2                    0.26837 0.13324 -6.68e-08 -3.87e-11      10      10
spacing.1                    0.71905 0.02697  5.41e-07 -1.24e-11      10      10
factor(age)2                -0.10907 0.11350  1.44e-07  2.25e-11      10      10
factor(age)3                -0.11255 0.12035  1.98e-07 -1.02e-11      10      10
factor(age)4                -0.46439 0.13011  1.21e-07  1.84e-10       9       9
factor(age)5                -0.62486 0.15949  7.76e-08  2.49e-10       9       9
factor(age)6                -0.59610 0.23786  3.81e-08 -3.35e-11      10      10
factor(emp)1                -0.49171 0.13797  8.41e-08  1.19e-10       9       9
factor(emp)2                 0.15125 0.18109  8.46e-08  1.13e-10       9       9
factor(emp)3                -0.20486 0.10517  1.42e-07  1.94e-10       9       9
factor(emp)4                -0.22147 0.08791  2.60e-07  7.14e-11       9       9
factor(cat)2                 0.36656 0.08827  5.69e-07 -1.71e-10       9       9
factor(born)2               -0.48732 0.09627  6.57e-07 -1.76e-11      10      10
factor(live)2                0.65045 0.09109  6.58e-07 -3.57e-11      10      10
factor(born)2:factor(live)2 -1.24764 0.13230  6.54e-07  2.37e-09       8       9

Eigen values of Hessian:
4082.051 2375.764 1235.911  394.007  303.612  274.623  201.763  160.835  142.713  107.139   77.548   62.710   45.448   34.078   18.440    9.721 

Convergence message from clm:
(0) successful convergence 
In addition: Absolute and relative convergence criteria were met 

convergence(model5)#best model with alternate threshold
 nobs logLik   niter max.grad cond.H  logLik.Error
 1516 -2187.23 6(0)  1.57e-10 4.3e+02 <1e-10      

                            Estimate Std.Err  Gradient     Error Cor.Dec Sig.Dig
threshold.1                  -0.7011 0.13203 -1.57e-10 -9.31e-15      13      13
spacing                       0.5616 0.01824 -4.59e-11 -1.94e-15      14      14
factor(age)2                 -0.1029 0.11284  3.41e-11 -1.56e-15      14      14
factor(age)3                 -0.1077 0.11980  4.77e-11 -7.02e-15      13      13
factor(age)4                 -0.4537 0.12942  2.82e-11  3.18e-14      13      13
factor(age)5                 -0.6140 0.15892  1.78e-11  4.25e-14      13      13
factor(age)6                 -0.5821 0.23637  8.97e-12 -2.19e-14      13      13
factor(emp)1                 -0.4842 0.13741  1.95e-11  1.38e-14      13      13
factor(emp)2                  0.1455 0.18009  2.00e-11  2.99e-14      13      13
factor(emp)3                 -0.2012 0.10486  3.34e-11  3.96e-14      13      13
factor(emp)4                 -0.2144 0.08762  6.19e-11  1.29e-14      13      13
factor(cat)2                  0.3580 0.08787  1.36e-10 -3.17e-14      13      13
factor(born)2                -0.4728 0.09597  1.56e-10 -5.41e-15      13      13
factor(live)2                 0.6475 0.09066  1.56e-10 -8.60e-15      13      13
factor(born)2:factor(live)2  -1.2158 0.13183  1.56e-10  5.65e-13      11      12

Eigen values of Hessian:
4555.81 2101.69  393.33  309.42  278.80  206.18  161.76  144.23  110.23   79.94   76.03   46.23   35.58   21.02   10.51 

Convergence message from clm:
(0) successful convergence 
In addition: Absolute and relative convergence criteria were met 

AIC(model2,model3,model4,model5)#model3 then 4
       df      AIC
model2 17 4342.095
model3 17 4299.337
model4 16 4303.208
model5 15 4404.467


anova(model2,model3)   # p>0.05 should be expected ?#(to be confirmed) #ie.pvalue of >0.05 to expect when comparing basic model with  best model with link only and Pvalue of <0.05 when comparing basic model with  best model with best model with link and threshold#
Likelihood ratio tests of cumulative link models:
 
       formula:                                                                                 link: 
model2 factor(fer_live) ~ factor(age) + factor(emp) + factor(cat) + factor(born) * factor(live) logit 
model3 factor(fer_live) ~ factor(age) + factor(emp) + factor(cat) + factor(born) * factor(live) loglog
       threshold:
model2 flexible  
model3 flexible  

       no.par    AIC  logLik LR.stat df Pr(>Chisq)
model2     17 4342.1 -2154.0                      
model3     17 4299.3 -2132.7  42.758  0           
> anova(model2,model4)   # p<0.05 should be expected ?#
Likelihood ratio tests of cumulative link models:
 
       formula:                                                                                 link: 
model4 factor(fer_live) ~ factor(age) + factor(emp) + factor(cat) + factor(born) * factor(live) loglog
model2 factor(fer_live) ~ factor(age) + factor(emp) + factor(cat) + factor(born) * factor(live) logit 
       threshold:
model4 symmetric 
model2 flexible  

       no.par    AIC  logLik LR.stat df Pr(>Chisq)
model4     16 4303.2 -2135.6                      
model2     17 4342.1 -2154.0 -36.887  1          1
> anova (model3,model4)  # there is a difference between the two - model 3 has the best AIC is not sig diff to the basic model
Likelihood ratio tests of cumulative link models:
 
       formula:                                                                                 link: 
model4 factor(fer_live) ~ factor(age) + factor(emp) + factor(cat) + factor(born) * factor(live) loglog
model3 factor(fer_live) ~ factor(age) + factor(emp) + factor(cat) + factor(born) * factor(live) loglog
       threshold:
model4 symmetric 
model3 flexible  

       no.par    AIC  logLik LR.stat df Pr(>Chisq)  
model4     16 4303.2 -2135.6                        
model3     17 4299.3 -2132.7  5.8713  1    0.01539 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> slice.model3 <- slice(model3, lambda = 5)
> par(mfrow = c(3, 3)) 
> plot(slice.model3)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: slice.model4 <- slice(model4, lambda = 5)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: par(mfrow = c(3, 3))
> plot(slice.model4)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: slice2.model3 <- slice(model3, lambda = 1e-5)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: par(mfrow = c(3, 3))
> plot(slice2.model3)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: summary(model3)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
> 
> summary(model3)
formula: factor(fer_live) ~ factor(age) + factor(emp) + factor(cat) + factor(born) * factor(live)
data:    dframe1

 link   threshold nobs logLik   AIC     niter max.grad cond.H 
 loglog flexible  1516 -2132.67 4299.34 6(1)  6.62e-07 4.7e+02

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
factor(age)2                -0.10695    0.11323  -0.945 0.344905    
factor(age)3                -0.11388    0.12008  -0.948 0.342918    
factor(age)4                -0.46521    0.12984  -3.583 0.000340 ***
factor(age)5                -0.62302    0.15928  -3.911 9.18e-05 ***
factor(age)6                -0.59415    0.23735  -2.503 0.012303 *  
factor(emp)1                -0.49107    0.13774  -3.565 0.000364 ***
factor(emp)2                 0.14932    0.18078   0.826 0.408794    
factor(emp)3                -0.20507    0.10500  -1.953 0.050814 .  
factor(emp)4                -0.22115    0.08774  -2.521 0.011717 *  
factor(cat)2                 0.36442    0.08810   4.136 3.53e-05 ***
factor(born)2               -0.47815    0.09619  -4.971 6.67e-07 ***
factor(live)2                0.66766    0.09115   7.325 2.39e-13 ***
factor(born)2:factor(live)2 -1.24591    0.13211  -9.431  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2 -0.71917    0.13321  -5.399
2|3 -0.06013    0.13240  -0.454
3|4  0.23825    0.13344   1.785
4|5  1.03920    0.13908   7.472
(34 observations deleted due to missingness)
> coef=(exp(model3$beta)) 
> cbind(ExpCo = coef(model3), confint(model3))  #Combines exp(coef(model3 or any model)) & confint(model3 or any model) into 1 table (in this case model3)#
                                 ExpCo      2.5 %        97.5 %
factor(age)2                -0.7191704 -0.3266992  0.1173825962
factor(age)3                -0.0601261 -0.3470028  0.1239003467
factor(age)4                 0.2382492 -0.7186629 -0.2093729597
factor(age)5                 1.0391975 -0.9385995 -0.3135565638
factor(age)6                -0.1069512 -1.0639121 -0.1326909984
factor(emp)1                -0.1138815 -0.7640834 -0.2236992804
factor(emp)2                -0.4652111 -0.2118924  0.4972905787
factor(emp)3                -0.6230215 -0.4116529  0.0002396612
factor(emp)4                -0.5941549 -0.3918653 -0.0477865724
factor(cat)2                -0.4910696  0.1944699  0.5400282410
factor(born)2                0.1493242 -0.6682511 -0.2909635212
factor(live)2               -0.2050748  0.4883540  0.8458025663
factor(born)2:factor(live)2 -0.2211455 -1.5040782 -0.9860726440

Warning message:
In cbind(ExpCo = coef(model3), confint(model3)) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
> round(exp(model3$beta), 2)
               factor(age)2                factor(age)3                factor(age)4 
                       0.90                        0.89                        0.63 
               factor(age)5                factor(age)6                factor(emp)1 
                       0.54                        0.55                        0.61 
               factor(emp)2                factor(emp)3                factor(emp)4 
                       1.16                        0.81                        0.80 
               factor(cat)2               factor(born)2               factor(live)2 
                       1.44                        0.62                        1.95 
factor(born)2:factor(live)2 
                       0.29 
> round(exp(confint(model3, type = "Wald")), 2)
                            2.5 % 97.5 %
1|2                          0.38   0.63
2|3                          0.73   1.22
3|4                          0.98   1.65
4|5                          2.15   3.71
factor(age)2                 0.72   1.12
factor(age)3                 0.71   1.13
factor(age)4                 0.49   0.81
factor(age)5                 0.39   0.73
factor(age)6                 0.35   0.88
factor(emp)1                 0.47   0.80
factor(emp)2                 0.81   1.65
factor(emp)3                 0.66   1.00
factor(emp)4                 0.67   0.95
factor(cat)2                 1.21   1.71
factor(born)2                0.51   0.75
factor(live)2                1.63   2.33
factor(born)2:factor(live)2  0.22   0.37
```